# select which document to load depending on the url load()

Tags: javascript, load

Hello I will start by an apologize for my english I am not to good at it, but I hope I can get my answer here.

I have a menu with `load()` function and it works great but I have two little problems.
To explain it i will give you examples.

My menu is something like this:

-Home
 -Movies
 -Contact

And when I click movies it loads `movies.php` and the link gets like this:

`www.server.com/#!/movies`

And thats great because I needed a link like that but if you copy and paste that same link to the browser it gives the deafult data so it doesnt have the `movies.php` loaded, I need that when I paste the link `www.server.com/#!/contact` it haves the div with `contact.php` loaded.

And also its just a little thing I will like, how can i put a loading image while the `load()` charges the rest of the page.

Comment: Can you post your `load` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is called "Routing" and isn't super easy to invent from scratch. I would recommend using something like [Crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/) to help you get your routing down. Crossroads is a library that only does Routing. It allows you to "deep-link" your pages like you are wanting to do. Libraries like Backbone.js and Sammyjs allow you the same type of routing functionality with deep-linking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to *maintains the state* of you pages based on the URL.

```
// Handle the `load` event for the page.
window.load = function() {

  // Get what follow the `hash` (#) from the URL.
  var hash = location.hash;

  // Compare and do your stuff.
  if (hash === '#!/movies')
    load('movies.php');
  ...
};
```

HTH (Hope this helps)